# Quickest way to write logging/stats data - file, database or url to external service

Tags: database, performance, http, logging

I am running a high volume web service and want to track the number of times the service gets called (per customer). However, I want the logging/writing of this data to have minimal impact on the overall time taken to process the service request.

I have thought of three ways:

1. Write to file (would need to open the file, read the 'hit count', increment and write back)
2. Write to database (write to a table and increment the 'hit count' against a given customer)
3. Fire off a URL call to some other service that can worry about storing the data

I like the 3rd option for architecture and coherence, but would firing an HTTP request be more 'costly' than either of the first options 1 or 2?

Comment: How much do you care about the accuracy of the logging? Does it matter if it misses some service calls? Does it have to be totally up to date all the time or is it ok for yesterdays data to be correct but the log for the last second to be not be up to date (yet)?

Answer (score 2):

You could front the WebService with the Apache HTTP Server, and log requests directly from there.  Logging requests would then be 100% ancillary to your application container, meaning no coupling to the application itself.  You could track per-customer by looking at request headers and/or parsing/rewriting the URL.

Check out the "Access Log" here:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html